# Another bad audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Here is another question which should be removed from audits:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256550/how-to-extract-links-from-text

[image: Bad audit]

My spider-sense told me that this was an audit, so I chose "vote to close" to pass it, but I do not see serious problems with it. Please remove it from audits.

Btw. the question is *not* on hold currently (it has even 0 close votes).

Comment: `(it has even 0 close votes)`... that isn't an entirely fair statement.  It had 5 close votes, but was edited and subsequently reopened.  It is possible the audit was selected based on the original state and not the current state.  However, if that is the case, that suggests that known bad audits should be removed if they are edited because of situations like this.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, of course, I assumed that this was the case. But I wanted to implicitly suggest, that questions should not be in such an audit when it does not have a single close vote at the moment.

Comment: imho, agree that it should be removed, looks more like a question needing an edit rather than being closed